# Field crew scheduling software?

Tags: calendar

We have:
-a list of tasks to do (taking 2 hrs to 5 days each, at jobs sites scattered across 4 counties, with individual due dates from 2 days to 4 weeks)
-a list of field crews (different skill sets and different skill levels, vacation and sick leave, all crews must work 40 hrs per week etc)
-a list of equipment
-a list of vehicles
-separate timesheet and billing software that is already bought and paid for

Whats the best way to organize this in an optimal schedule? Currently, it takes one person 4 to 6 hrs per day to create a schedule for 15 two man crews in Google Calendar.  The schedule is constantly being revised as calls and emails come into the office, which is frustrating.  This seems like it should be easier than it is.

Thank you!

Comment: what's the budget you have in mind? Is it different from zero (or do you expect it to be free)? And how much effort are you willing to do to get it implemented, everybody trained in it, etc? And by when? And what infrastructure do you have to run it (secure?) across the globe?

Comment: In general for these sorts of questions you need to do more homework.  Google "Scheduling software" do some trials and tell us what doesn't work and why.  That said, I'm amazed that you got Google Calendar to work for you at all for this without going crazy.

Comment: I've looked at some software, but it doesnt seem to do exactly what we need.  Theres shift scheduling software that can manage days off, but the crews are scheduled by the job